# Gradle changes android manifest tags

Tags: android, build.gradle

I've been experimenting with the gradle build system and I've ran into a weird issue. When I compile the project using

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false"/>
```

in my manifest using gradle, I check the manifest for debug and I see

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true"/>
```

Is there some way I can change that?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "I check the manifest for debug"?

Comment: When I go to build>manifests>debug I see my regular manifest but that library is now required instead of optional.

Comment: "When I go to build>manifests>debug" -- what does that mean? Are you referring to Android Studio?

Comment: I'm just referring to the build folder created after using gradle. Every module gets a build folder where it breaks down all the modifications made. So in this case to look at the APks generated I would go to MODULE/build/apks . So to look at the manifests I go to MODULE/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: "I'm just referring to the build folder created after using gradle" -- ah, so `>` is `/`.

Comment: Ya that was a silly notation to use, sorry.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot reproduce your problem. I just took one of my projects that has `android:required="false"`, had Eclipse generate `build.gradle`, fixed it to have `compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:10"`, and ran the `assembleDebug` task. My `build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` file still has `android:required="false"`.

Comment: Just in case you were curious I figured I would deliver the thrilling conclusion. Along the build process I had a manifest that has left the android:required tag off and that was causing it to flip to required. Thanks for looking into my issue tho @CommonsWare.